# Room Typeconverter conversion

Tags: type-conversion, android-room

I have a custom made object having Type String and boolean:

```
public class MyItem {
    private String string;
    private boolean bool;
}
```

I have Room Object:

```
@Entity
public class Checklist {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private final String title;
    private final ArrayList<MyItem> items;
}
```

How can i convert using Typeconverter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. create a class for the type converters
2. add 2 public methods to the class, each annotated with `@TypeConverter` *( note **not** the plural `@TypeConverters`)*

   1. One method will need to convert and return the respective field into a single type that is supported by Room. Typically a `String`
   2. The other method will need to convert, the type returned by the other method, again typically a String, into the respective field type.
3. Add an `@TypeConverters` annotation including the class, note the plural, with sufficient scope (see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverters). Coding the `@TypeConverts` annotation at the `@Database` level provides the greatest scope.

As an example, that DOES NOT actually convert the data, but demonstrates the above.

1-2 inclusive

:-

```
class MyRoomTypeConverters {

    @TypeConverter
    public ArrayList<MyItem> fromStringToMyItemArrayList(String stringFromDB) {
        ArrayList<MyItem> rv = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
        return rv;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public String fromMyItemArrayListToString(ArrayList<MyItem> myItemArrayList) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

3. 

:-

```
@TypeConverters(MyRoomTypeConverters.class) /* <<<<<<<<<< */
@Database(entities = {Checklist.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
public abstract class TestDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
```

With the above instead of getting the compile/build error `Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. - items in`  the project them compiles successfully *(but **NOTE** the actual data returned from the converters is useless)*.

You need to embed code, in the methods, that will actually convert the data.
A frequent way to convert from and to a string is to use a **gson** library, of which there are a number.

However, from a database perspective, storing a list has disadvantages as all the data from the underlying objects/variables has to take the form of a single variable. This single variable will contain bloat in the way of
object/variable identifiers and separators which increase the amount of data stored and may well complicate use of the data, such as for when querying the database.

e.g. if there were 2 MYItems in the list then what is stored could be something along the lines of `[{"bool":true,"string":"MI1"},{"bool":false,"string":"MI2"}]`

From the database perspective, the type converted should, in most situations be a separate but related table.